# partitioning and selecting clusters with multiple records

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, ranking

The header of question might be confusing so I put my issue into words:

I have a table with master_ids, ids and years. A master_id can contain different ids. Each Id is associated with a year. I already partitioned by master_id and gave each year a rank (year_rank).

```
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
| master_id | id | year | year_rank |
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
| 100       | 1  | 2017 | 1         |
| 100       | 2  | 2016 | 2         |
| 100       | 3  | 2015 | 3         |
| 200       | 9  | 2001 | 1         |
| 300       | 5  | 2020 | 1         |
| 300       | 4  | 2010 | 2         |
| 400       | 7  | 1999 | 1         |
| 400       | 11 | 1996 | 2         |
| 500       | 20 | 1999 | 1         |
| 600       | 25 | 2005 | 1         |
| 600       | 29 | 2005 | 1         |
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
```

My goal is to pick only the clusters which have more than 1 record in order to compare it:

```
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
| master_id | id | year | year_rank |
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
| 100       | 1  | 2017 | 1         |
| 100       | 2  | 2016 | 2         |
| 100       | 3  | 2015 | 3         |
| 300       | 5  | 2020 | 1         |
| 300       | 4  | 2010 | 2         |
| 400       | 7  | 1999 | 1         |
| 400       | 11 | 1996 | 2         |
+-----------+----+------+-----------+
```

If I put where year_rank > 1 it eliminates the first rows in the clusters with multiple records which I don't want. How can I solve this? I thought about a group by but I don't know how to apply this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Completely updated for new requirement. This will only show records for master_ids which have multiple years associated with them, however it will show all records associated for that master_id even if they are in the same year (see 600 vs 700).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68fc2/1/0)

We will perform your year_rank in cte1 so we can aggregate it with the MAX() function in cte2 to filter out where max is greater than whatever variable you want to put there. We then query cte1 and join on cte2 to only show the records for master_ids that have multiple years associated with them.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        master_id,
        id,
        year,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY year DESC) AS year_rank
    FROM tbl
    ),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        master_id
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY master_id
    HAVING MAX(year_rank) > 1
    )

SELECT
    cte1.master_id,
    cte1.id,
    cte1.year,
    cte1.year_rank
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON
    cte1.master_id = cte2.master_id
```

Comment: I think it should be order by year desc but OP is not very clear

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much for this solution. This works pretty well but if a master_id with 2 sub_ids has the same year it will rank it as a but the master_id count will be two and will not eliminate that. I really want to display the master_ids which have sub_ids with different years. How can we do this?

Comment: See example above (master_id = 600). I added this extra.

Comment: Suppose 600, in addition to its 2 2005 records, had a 2006 record. Would we then want to show all 3 records, or just 1 2005 and the 2006? If just 1 2005, which one?

Comment: None of them within the group with the 600 master_id. Because there is no discrepancy between the years. Both of the records with the master_id 600 have the same year so I don't want to display them. My idea is to work with a case statement and compare if the year and lead(year) are the same and assign notes. What would you suggest?

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien please check out my solution which I posted below.

Comment: My question is, if in addition to the existing records, there was a record with a separate year. Please review http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68fc2/1/0. Specifically, the 700 master_id. Is that displaying as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to eliminate rows which don't have a discrepancy in years within their master_id:

```
select *,
case
  when (master_id = (lead(master_id) over (order by master_id))) and 
  (year = (lead(service_year) over (order by master_id))) then 'no show'

  when (master_id = (lag(master_id) over (order by master_id))) and 
  (year = (lag(service_year) over (order by master_id))) then 'no show'
  else ''
end as note
from table
```

Now I can put all of that into a temp table and delete the records which have 'no show' in the note column.

What do you think of this? Is there an easier way?

Comment: There is an easier way. Instead of using a temp table or etl process, you can choose not to select this in your original case statement.